# How do I implement tsql's sum(...) over () in linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this functional t-sql query that counts the entries in a group by clause, and at the same time produces a percentage of the count compared to the entire set.

It is blazing fast (~90 ms) in Azure. I'd like to implement in a similar manner with LINQ to SQL, but I can't figure it out...

```
select f.worktype, f.counted, (100.0 * f.counted)/ (sum(f.counted) over ()) as percentage
from
(SELECT 
    wa.skillEN  AS workType,
    count(wa.skillEN) counted
FROM [dbo].WorkAssignments as WA 
join [dbo].WorkOrders as WO ON (WO.ID = WA.workorderID) 
WHERE wo.dateTimeOfWork < ('1/1/2014') 
and wo.dateTimeOfWork > ('1/1/2013')
and wo.statusEN = 'Completed'
group by wa.skillEN) as f
group by f.worktype, f.counted
```

The LINQ I've been trying in LINQPad...

```
WorkAssignments
.Where(wa => wa.WorkOrder.DateTimeofWork > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)
          && wa.WorkOrder.DateTimeofWork < DateTime.Now)
.GroupBy(wa => wa.SkillEN)
.Select(g => new
{
    label = g.Key,
    count = g.Count()
})
.GroupBy(g => new {g.label, g.count})
.Select(gg => new
{
  label = gg.Key.label,
  count = gg.Key.count,
  pct = gg.Sum(a => a.count)
})
```

(The dates in the where clause are slightly different, but I don't think it's relevant)

So, how would I implement the `over ()` feature in LINQ to SQL?